# How to change root css variables in Vue js so that it can be further used in naming tailwind classes? [solved]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I have been trying my best to achieve an effect where upon **changing the song in a music player, the image and the color scheme changes as well**. This was possible when I made the music player using tailwindCSS and Vanilla Javascript. But it has been difficult for me to find a way to achieve the same using Vue.

While using Vanilla JS, I could write this in my JS and HTML file  respectively:

```js
function loadsong(music) {
    song.innerText = music.song
    artist.innerHTML = music.artist
    audio.src = music.songUrl
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-color', music.prColor)
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--secondary-color', music.secColor)
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--img-link', music.imageSrc)
}
```

```html
<style>
      :root{
        --primary-color: null;
        --secondary-color: null;
        --img-link: null;
      }
    </style>
    
    <script>
    tailwind.config = {
      theme: {
        colors: {
          primary: 'var(--primary-color)',
          secondary: 'var(--secondary-color)',
        },
        extend: {
          backgroundImage: {
            'image': 'var(--img-link)'
          },
        }
      },
    }
  </script>
```

but when I try doing this in Vue JS:

```js
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      current: {},
      index: 0,
      isPlaying: false,
      player: new Audio(),
      songData: [{ //an object for example
        imageSrc: require('./assets/Images/Laufey.png'),
        song: 'I Wish You Love',
        songUrl: require('./assets/audio/Laufey - I Wish You Love.mp3'),
        artist: 'Laufey',
        prColor: '#46352E',
        secColor: '#CCC6C4',
        heart: true
      }],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    next() {
      this.index++
        this.current = this.songData[this.index]
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.current = this.songData[this.index]

    let root = document.documentElement.style
    root.setProperty('--primary-color', this.current.prColor)
    root.setProperty('--secondary-color', this.current.secColor)
    root.setProperty('--img-link', `url(${this.current.imageSrc})`)

    this.player.src = this.current.songUrl

    console.log(this.current)
  }
} <
/script>
```

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@layer base {
   :root {
    --primary-color: null;
    --secondary-color: null;
    --img-link: null;
  }
}
```

This does not work. I wanted that everytime I change the song, the script reads the new song object (which it does since it grabs other elements) grabs the colors I have defined in the object and pass it on to the root CSS variables. Can someone help me out with this?

Edit: When I used computed method to grab onto the root values and update them, it worked!

Comment: I am not sure you can initiate a custom property with 'null'. unless this is some vue syntax you have to set a valid value to the property to be able to change it.

Comment: @RicardoSilva But when I manually change the array index of songData, it does apply the changes that I want. I don't understand why it doesn't work when the script is running.

Comment: I don't know much vue. But I then suspect the block u use to set the properties on the create method is never run. Try to put a 'debugger' before the setProperty call. Or try to run the setaproperty from the devtools console and see if it works.